# Input field unselects when I try and update

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to update the input value on a form. The input value I need to update sits within an array of objects within another array of objects. I'm trying to update the address within emails (see below).

```
const userProfiles = [{
firstName: 'John',
emails: [{ address: 'john@gmail.com' }]
}]
```

Each keystroke updates the field and sate of the userProfiles, however, the input field disengages. So I have to keep reselecting the input field. What am I missing here?

```
handleInputChange = (userProfileId, index) => (event) => {
  const target = event.target;
  const value = target.value;
  const name = target.name;

  const userProfiles = this.state.userProfiles.map((userProfile) => {
    if (userProfile._id === userProfileId) {
      if (name === 'email') {
        const emails = userProfile.emails.map((email, idx) => {
          if (idx === index) {
            return {
              ...email,
              address: value,
            };
          }
          return {
            ...email,
          };
        });

        return {
          ...userProfile,
          emails,
        };
      }

      return {
        ...userProfile,
        [name]: value,
      };
    }
    return {
      ...userProfile,
    };
  });

  this.setState({
    userProfiles,
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an example on jsfiddle/codepen ?

Comment: Sorry, the problem turned out to be the key. I was using the email address as the key. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
handleInputChange = (userProfileId, index) => (event) => {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    let { userProfiles } = this.state;
    userProfiles.map((eachProfile) => {
        let { emails } = userProfiles.emails;
        if (userProfile._id === userProfileId) {
            if(name === 'email') {
                emails.map((emails, idx) => {
                    if (idx === index) {
                        emails = value;
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    });
    this.setState({
        ...this.state,
        userProfiles
    })
}
```

Can you try this one?